# Android - portrait and landscape orientations?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am learning android development and I have made a calculator app for practice. It works fine in portrait mode. So I made a new xml file for landscape after the app is not even working in portrait mode. As soon as it starts, it crashes with the message "Unfortunately app has stopped working". Here is my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Stack;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public char[] ch1=new char[20];
public char[] tempch=new char[20];
int result=0,i,len,j;
String char1="",temp,t="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void one(View view) {
    char1+="1";
    display();
}
public void two(View view) {
    char1+="2";
    display();
}
public void three(View view) {
    char1+="3";
    display();
}
public void four(View view) {
    char1+="4";
    display();
}
public void five(View view) {
    char1+="5";
    display();
}
public void six(View view) {
    char1+="6";
    display();
}
public void seven(View view) {
    char1+="7";
    display();
}
public void eight(View view) {
    char1+="8";
    display();
}
public void nine(View view) {
    char1+="9";
    display();
}
public void zero(View view) {
    char1+="0";
    display();
}
public void openb(View view) {
    char1 +="(";
    display();
}
public void closeb(View view) {
    char1+=")";
    display();
}
public void calc(View view) {
    TextView quantityTextViewdel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
    temp=quantityTextViewdel.getText().toString();
    if (temp.compareTo(t)==0)
    {
        char1="";
        display();
    }
    else
    {
        //test code
        j=0;
        tempch=char1.toCharArray();
        len=char1.length();
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(tempch[i]))
            {
                ch1[j++] = tempch[i];
            }
            else if (Character.isWhitespace(tempch[i]))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ch1[j++]=' ';
                ch1[j++]=tempch[i];
                ch1[j++]=' ';

            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            tempch[i]='\0';
        }
        char1=""+String.valueOf(ch1);
        for (i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            ch1[i]='\0';
        }
        result=evaluate(char1);
        char1=""+result;
        j=0;
        display();
    }

}
public void add(View view) {
    char1+="+";
    display();
}
public void sub(View view) {
    char1+="-";
    display();
}
public void mul(View view) {
    char1+="*";
    display();
}
public void div(View view) {
    char1+="/";
    display();
}

public void del(View view) {
    TextView quantityTextViewdel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
    temp=quantityTextViewdel.getText().toString();
    if (temp.compareTo(t)==0)
    {
        char1="";
        display();
    }
    else
    {
        char1=""+char1.substring(0,char1.length()-1);
        display();
    }

}
public void clear(View view) {
    char1="";
    display();
}
/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display() {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
    quantityTextView.setText(char1);
}
private int evaluate(String expression)
{
    char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();

    // Stack for numbers: 'values'
    Stack<Integer> values = new Stack<Integer>();

    // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
    Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
        if (tokens[i] == ' ')
            continue;

        // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
        if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
        {
            StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
            // There may be more than one digits in number
            while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <='9')
                sbuf.append(tokens[i++]);
            values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString()));
        }

        // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
        else if (tokens[i] == '(')
            ops.push(tokens[i]);

            // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
        else if (tokens[i] == ')')
        {
            while (ops.peek() != '(')
                values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
            ops.pop();
        }

        // Current token is an operator.
        else if (tokens[i] == '+' || tokens[i] == '-' ||
                tokens[i] == '*' || tokens[i] == '/')
        {
            // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
            // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
            // to top two elements in values stack
            while (!ops.empty() && hasPrecedence(tokens[i], ops.peek()))
                values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));

            // Push current token to 'ops'.
            ops.push(tokens[i]);
        }
    }

    // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
    // ops to remaining values
    try {
        while (!ops.empty())
            values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
    }
    catch(EmptyStackException e1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
    return values.pop();
}

// Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
// otherwise returns false.
private boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
        return false;
    if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

// A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a'
// and 'b'. Return the result.
private int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                        UnsupportedOperationException("Cannotdividebyzero");
            return a / b;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/res"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:hint="value"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="two"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="three"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="four"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="five"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="six"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="sub"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="seven"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="eight"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="nine"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="mul"
        android:text="*"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="clear"
                android:text="clr"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="zero"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="del"
                android:text="del"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="openb"
                android:text="("
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="div"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="closeb"
                android:text=")"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="calc"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

res/layout-land/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/res"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:hint="value"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="60sp" />

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="one"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="two"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="three"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="35sp" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="four"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="35sp" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="sub"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="five"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="six"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="seven"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="eight"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="35sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="nine"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="zero"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="mul"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="div"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="35sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="clear"
                android:text="clr"
                android:textSize="30sp" />



            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="del"
                android:text="del"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="openb"
                android:text="("
                android:textSize="35sp" />



            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="closeb"
                android:text=")"
                android:textSize="35sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="calc"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The way in which i have arranged layout and layout-land folders in res folder

res/

layout/

activity_main.xml

layout-land\

activity_main.xml

minsdk is 11

targetsdk is 21

logcat file

```
06-24 11:09:38.059  32152-32152/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication, PID: 32152
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication/com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.mabhi_000.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210        
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)           
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)        
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

</style>

</resources>
```

what am i doing wrong can anyone tell me?

Comment: Post your stacktrace (exception thrown)

Comment: What does logCat say?

Comment: copy and paste the message from the LogCat.

Comment: could you also add the styles.xml placed in your res/values-folder?

Comment: @mabhi95a10 always check your Log. it has its own answer. **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your res/values-folder open the styles.xml file and edit the line

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

other possibilities for the parent attribute are

```
Theme.AppCompat
Theme.AppCompat.Light
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Comment: thank for help after changing to Theme.AppCompact my app is working.But why it did not work for Theme.Holo

Comment: Your are using the android compatibility aka support lib. These libs allow you to develop your app for older plattforms, which e.g. do not support Fragments natively. As a side effect you have to use those Theme.AppCompat.* themes to make this support libs work.